# Object maping in ES next

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-next

I have an array of object with a status property:

```
[{
...
status: 'enable'
},{
...
status: 'enable'
}...]
```

the status property can have 2 values: `'enable'/'disable'`.

If status 'enable' I would like to set it to disable and vice-versa.

Instead of doing following:

```
if(obj.status === 'enable') 
    obj.status = 'disable'
else 
    obj.status = 'enable'
```

I would like to map the enable status to a true boolean (and disable to false) and do the following:

```
Mapping[obj.status] = !Mapping[obj.status] // this should change the status value
```

is it possible?

Comment: what about using a getter / setter instead? so that you can switch the status value by altering a getter value.

Comment: That's a possibility :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take an object for changing the value.

```
const change = { enable: 'disable', disable: 'enable' };

// in loop
obj.status = change[obj.status];
```

Comment: Ah, I like the idea of a separate object here - nice work